# How do I really, truly, update all dependencies with NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

How do I (recursively) update all dependencies with NPM?

My usual approach (using `npm-check-updates`) is this:

```sh
ncu -u                   # updates my package.json to contain the newest versions of my dependencies
npm install              # installs what ncu has written to package.json
npm update --depth 99999 # recursively updates packages to the newest version within the specified range
```

However, this does not work, and often leaves the dependencies in a state where `npm audit` will complain about sub-dependencies. (Or, worse, `npm update --depth 99999` sometimes hangs.)

Running `npm audit fix` will update more packages, but only to fix security vulnerabilities.

The only true solution I've found is this:

```sh
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules # remove any trace of the old packages
npm install                           # start fresh
```

…but this can't be the right solution, right? **Right?**

I'm surprised I have to ask this here, but reading the documentation and searching the internet for some time has only yielded `npm update --depth 99999` and the `npm-check-updates` package, which don't fully do the job.